# How to print a specific part of a data structure using python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, data-structures, dataframe

I have this python data structure

```
data = {
    "Max": { 
        "Job": "Accountant", 
        "YOB": "1985", 
        "Children": ["John", "Tom"]
        }, 
    "Roit": {
        "Job": "Programmer", 
        "YOB": "1990"
        }
}
```

Using python how can print specific parts of this data structure:
Such as printing the job Roits job, and the second of Max's children.

Comment: Can you include the exact output you are expecting and also please show us your attempt to achieve your result.

Comment: What do you mean by `the second part of Max`?

Comment: Such as printing the job Roits job, and the second of Max's children.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict[key]` to get value that correspond to the `key` in the dictionary.

```
>>> data = {
...     "Max": {
...         "Job": "Accountant",
...         "YOB": "1985",
...         "Children": ["John", "Tom"]
...         },
...     "Roit": {
...         "Job": "Programmer",
...         "YOB": "1990"
...         }
... }
>>> data['Roit']['Job']
'Programmer'
>>> data['Max']['Job']
'Accountant'
>>> data['Max']['Children']
['John', 'Tom']
>>> data['Max']['Children'][1]  # <-- to access list item, use index (starting from 0)
'Tom'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(data['Roit']['Job'])
```

will be fine for printing "the job Roits job" (I assume -- this takes some interpretation:).

However there's no such thing as "second part of Max" (for all my excruciating attempts at interpretation!-).  `data['Max']` is a `dict` and as such has no "first part" or "second part".  Clarification of what exactly you mean is therefore urgently needed!

Added: upon the OP's clarifying in a comment (and edit to the original Q) that the ask was meant for "the second of Max's children",

```
print(data['Max']['Children'][1])
```

is clearly the answer to that.

Comment: Such as printing the job Roits job, and the second of Max's children.

Answer (score 0):

To print Riots job we can use:

```
print data ['Roit']['Job']
```